# How to transfer the name of a clicked image to another php page?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, onclick, transfer

I'm trying to open a video that corresponds to the thumbnail that was clicked. However when I'm directed to the page in which the video is supposed to appear, I get an error,

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'SELECT v_id FROM video WHERE image_name = \'$image_name\'\') ?>'

below is the page where the image is clicked,

```
<?php
$query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM video ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
while($all_video=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
?>
<a href="watchScreen.php? $v_id=mysqli_query($link, \'SELECT v_id FROM video WHERE image_name = \'$image_name\'\') ?>" onclick="open()" ><image src="thumbnails/<?php echo $all_video['image_name']; ?>" id="img" width="300" height="200"/></a>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function open() {

  var nameImg = document.getElementById("img").src;

  nameImg = "<?php $image_name ?>";
}
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Newxt is the watchScreen.php,

```
<?php
include "config.php";
session_start();
$_SESSION['v_id']=$_GET['$v_id']

$vid_id = $_SESSION['v_id'];
$myquery=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT video_name FROM video WHERE v_id=$vid_id");
while($my_video=mysqli_fetch_array($myquery))
{
?>
<video width="60%" height="60%" style="background-color:#585858; border: 4px solid darkorange; border-radius:20px;" controls>
<source src="uploads/<?php echo $play_vid['video_name']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<?php } ?>
```

Below is the mySQL table,

```
CREATE TABLE video(
v_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
video_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY user_id(id)
REFERENCES users(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
n_views INT,
image_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm now trying to figure out how I can send the name of the clicked image to watchScreen.php.

Comment: `watchScreen.php? $v_id=mysqli_query($link, \'SELECT v_id FROM video WHERE image_name = \'$image_name\'\') ?>` ?? this is NOT the way to do this

Comment: What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest, if I understood correctly, perhaps trying an approach like the following.

So it appears you simply need to send the `vid` value in the request to `watchScreen.php` which you obtain in the initial query. As the query returns all columns you can pick and choose which columns/fields you include in the HTML quite easily without the need for the erroneous query you had before.

```
<?php

    $query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM video ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
    while($all_video=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){


        printf('
            <a href="watchScreen.php?$v_id=%d" onclick="open(event)">
                <img src="thumbnails/%s" width=300 height=200 />
            </a>',
            $all_video['v_id'],
            $all_video['image_name']
        );
    }

?>
<script>
    /* 

        The `open` function doesn't actually do anything as it was... 
        Also, every ID MUST be unique... but there is no need to 
        assign an ID in this case as the image is a direct child
        of the `a` so can be accessed in a number of ways.
    */
    function open(e){
        var img = e.target.querySelector('img');
        alert( img.src );
    }

</script>
```

To process the request, because it has user input ( GET ), you really, really, really should use a prepared statement to try to avoid SQL injection attacks.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include "config.php";

    if( !empty( $_GET['$v_id'] ) ){

        $vid = $_SESSION['v_id'] = $_GET['$v_id'];

        $sql='SELECT video_name FROM video WHERE v_id=?';
        $stmt=$link->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $vid );
        $res=$stmt->execute();
        if( $res ){
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result( $videoname );
            $stmt->fetch();
            /* a literal `%` in either `printf` or `sprintf` should be escaped with another `%` ... */
            printf('
                <video width="60%%" height="60%%" style="background-color:#585858; border: 4px solid darkorange; border-radius:20px;" controls>
                    <source src="uploads/%s" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            ', $videoname );
        }
    } else {
        exit('missing ID');
    }

?>
```

None of the above has been tested so you may find some errors ( hopefully not too many though ) - hope it'll help

Comment: I no longer have my initial errror, however I'm now getting >>Warning: printf(): Too few arguments.

Comment: yep.. ok, I see why. Edited above - a single `%` that is NOT a placeholder in either `printf` or `sprintf` etc needs to be escaped with another `%` - becoming `%%` as the above demonstrates